# Edit string inside a p tag but not content inside other tags in it

Tags: javascript, html

I will just like to edit string inside a p tag (Some text) but ignore editing the span tag.

```
<p>
    Some text <span class="ipsEmoji"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Why not wrap "Some text" in a ```span``` element and give that a unique id or class.
```<p><span id="text">Some text</span> <span class="ipsEmoji"></span></p>```

Then using Javascript you could do:
```document.getElementbyId("text").innerHTML = "some other text";```

Comment: Also, why did you use the ```php``` tag?

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend starting by wrapping the text in another span:

```
<p>
    <span id="text">Some text</span> <span class="ipsEmoji"></span>
</p>
```

then you could use Javascript to access the html and change the contents of the text:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text") //this allows you to refer to the text area as "text"

// this will change the text to anything you want
text.innerHTML = " put whatever you want to change it to here "
```

just remember to keep the javascript capitalization correct.
to put all of this into the file, you can use the script tag:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--the tag below will allow you to put javascript in your html code, if you need help making it activate when something is clicked, let me know, i will do my best to help-->
        <script>
            var text = document.getElementById("text") //this allows you to refer to the text area as "text"

            // this will change the text to anything you want
            text.innerHTML = " put whatever you want to change it to here "
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <span id="text">Some text</span> <span class="ipsEmoji"></span>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```